My empty Ubuntu Server on VMware freezes 5 minutes after booting
I normally use Windows, but I installed ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.iso on VMware to develop my bash project. At first I thought the problem was in the RAM and CPU and I reinstalled it from scratch adding 8 cores 8GB RAM. I was low on free space so I cleaned the disk and I have 200GB free space.
ChatGPT advised me to turn off 3d hardware acceleration, which I did and reinstalled but it still freezes 5 minutes after booting.
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog
2024-10-06T14:56:38.022707+00:00 duran systemd[1191]: Listening on gpg-agent-ssh.socket - GnuPG cryptographic agent (ssh-agent emulation).
2024-10-06T14:56:38.022725+00:00 duran systemd[1191]: Reached target sockets.target - Sockets.
2024-10-06T14:56:38.022745+00:00 duran systemd[1191]: Reached target basic.target - Basic System.
2024-10-06T14:56:38.022766+00:00 duran systemd[1191]: Reached target default.target - Main User Target.
2024-10-06T14:56:38.022784+00:00 duran systemd[1191]: Startup finished in 110ms.
2024-10-06T14:56:38.022805+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Started user@1000.service - User Manager for UID 1000.
2024-10-06T14:56:38.022844+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Started session-1.scope - Session 1 of User duran.
2024-10-06T14:56:41.898522+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Starting ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server...
2024-10-06T14:56:41.920766+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Started ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server.
2024-10-06T14:56:43.514656+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Started session-3.scope - Session 3 of User duran.
2024-10-06T14:57:35.332857+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Started session-4.scope - Session 4 of User duran.
2024-10-06T14:58:07.198964+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Started session-5.scope - Session 5 of User duran.
2024-10-06T15:00:26.039952+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Starting sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool...
2024-10-06T15:00:26.045517+00:00 duran systemd[1]: sysstat-collect.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-10-06T15:00:26.045576+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Finished sysstat-collect.service - system activity accounting tool.
2024-10-06T15:01:37.489795+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Starting update-notifier-download.service - Download data for packages that failed at package install time...
2024-10-06T15:01:37.608769+00:00 duran systemd[1]: update-notifier-download.service: Deactivated successfully.
2024-10-06T15:01:37.608922+00:00 duran systemd[1]: Finished update-notifier-download.service - Download data for packages that failed at package install time.
2024-10-06T15:02:37.475061+00:00 duran systemd[1191]: launchpadlib-cache-clean.service - Clean up old files in the Launchpadlib cache was skipped because of an unmet condition check (ConditionPathExists=/home/duran/.launchpadlib/api.launchpad.net/cache).
2024-10-06T15:05:01.405332+00:00 duran CRON[1411]: (root) CMD (command -v debian-sa1 > /dev/null && debian-sa1 1 1)
2024-10-06T15:09:18.167306+00:00 duran kernel: workqueue: psi_avgs_work hogged CPU for >10000us 4 times, consider switching to WQ_UNBOUND
client_loop: send disconnect: Connection reset

Results of top :

VMware settings:

freeze:

I wonder why an empty Ubuntu server freezes now when it didn't freeze before.
